# I can't remove the white background color of the menu

Tags: colors, background

I've been trying to solve this problem all day without success.
I want to change de background color from my home page. For this i have use this CSS:

```
.page-id-6128 { 
background-color: #F5F5DC;
background-size: cover;
padding-top: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
min-height: 100vh;
background-position: 50% 100%;
}
```

The problem is that i can't remove the white background from the menu as you can see in the next image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9c2P.png

www.albertosotophotography.com/home

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this:

```
.navbar {
    background-color: #F5F5DC;
}
```

---

EDIT

Better solution - remove `background-color` property from your `.site` class. Now you have:

```
.site {
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. I´m very grateful.

Comment: @Alberto Soto On StackOverflow it is better to select the provided answer as a solution than thanking in a comment. It will in turn convey your gratitude to the answer provider and what is most important it will help future users with similar problem. Happy coding!

Comment: Ok! Thank you again!